# I'd like to make an array of combinations with python and bring one from there

Tags: python, combinations

There is an array of 512 lengths.

```
[0,1,2,3, ... , 510, 511]
```

Then, if I can pick 216 and come out as a combination, I want to get an arrangement of the numbers that I want.

I'm not good at explaining, so I'll give you a small number of examples.

array size is 6

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

i'd like to pick 4 from here
the list is

```
[0,1,2,3]
[0,1,2,4]
[0,1,2,5]
[0,2,3,4]
[0,2,3,5]
...
[2,3,4,5]
```

When I want to pick the forth one, I want to use this number to print the next one.

```
[0,2,3,4]
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: what's _the next one_?

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.combinations`

```py
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint 

numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
combs = [list(c) for c in combinations(numbers, 4)]
pprint(combs)

# if you're expecting a very large number of combinations, 
# you shouldn't convert them into lists, but loop over them directly
#
# large_list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3, ..., 511, 512]
# for c in combinations(large_list_of_numbers, 256):
#     print(c)
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 5],
 [0, 1, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 5],
 [0, 1, 4, 5],
 [0, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 2, 3, 5],
 [0, 2, 4, 5],
 [0, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 5],
 [1, 2, 4, 5],
 [1, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Then don't convert the combinations to a list, loop over them directly. I've revised my answer

Comment: Are you really trying to process a list of ~10^152 combinations? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=512C256. Because that will take a few trillion years to go through.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'd like to bring one of the largest numbers. crying